# Unable to run/create a maven project using tapestry 5 quickstart

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tapestry

I am using Eclipse Luna and JDK 1.7. I have also installed the Maven Integration for Luna and Run Jetty Run from Eclipse Marketplace. But when I create a Maven Project using tapestry.apache.org quickstart archetype, it shows a very different hierarchy and also the names of packages in the .java files do not match the hierarchy.

Package name in index.java is:
package project.compress.pages;

Actually, according to the hierarchy it should be:
package main.java.project.compress.pages;

Why is this happening? I did the exact same steps at the office today and it is not working here.

Also, there is a red cross on the project name(i.e compress) that indicates an error but there is no red cross in the complete hierarchy.

P.S: I am very new to all this so please do not get mad if it is a silly question. Please help me out here. I just have tomorrow's day for work.

Answer (score 0):

By default Maven puts all source code under src/main/java, so your package is fine. It should contain only folder underneath Java.

I don't understand where you see an error, however it seems like src/main/java is somehow not properly configured as a source root.